# Flutter not compiling code after upgrading to 1.27.0

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-errors, compilation, upgrade

i'm working on a Flutter project and it was working all fine but after i upgraded the flutter to latest version (1.27.0-9.0.pre.85 • channel master ), it is not compiling code. It is giving the following error
"Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'".

Here is the screenshot of my log:
[image]

Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: master should never be used to develope. If you want to have more stable things, use "dev" or "beta".

Comment: this version is also not working in neither of these two versions.

Comment: master, dev and beta doesn't have the same version... you need to do "flutter clean" and "flutter upgrade" every time you change channels

Comment: you should also check if those methods are deprecated.

Comment: It worked after downgrading to 1.26.0-1.0.pre